# Is there a JavaScript library that can remove ads from a web page?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a JavaScript library that will remove ads from a webpage in a similar way to how adblock works.

I would like to use it by injecting a script in to a webview on an iOS device (similar to how a content script could be used in a Chrome plugin).

Does such a thing exist? I've searched a lot on Google and Github but haven't found anything that fits my needs.

Comment: Adblock Plus uses lists of what elements aren't allowed. It wouldn't be *that* hard to intercept every DOM change and run it against those rules. It might be slow, though.

Answer (score 1):

[Adblock plus is on Github](https://github.com/adblockplus), you might be able to use something from it.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the ABP code makes calls to adblock servers which would require cross-domain XHR, which I don't have available to me.

Comment: Hmm in that case you could have some server-side code on your server that downloads the data from the ABP server and makes it available to your app. You could include the new data with every new release.